# vimdiff against a source control repo

Tags: version-control, vim, diff

[scmdiff](http://github.com/ghewgill/vim-scmdiff/tree/master) marks the differences between the checked in version of a file and the file that's being edited.  It marks it by coloring the changed lines.  Is there any way to view the changes using a `vimdiff`-style split instead of just coloring the changed lines?

For instance, if `abc` is a file under version control, then I can use the following to display the current version of `abc` on one side and the latest version on the other side:

```
tkdiff abc
```

I can also do:

```
tkdiff -r1 -r5 abc
```

to show the differences between versions 1 and 5.  Finally, I can do:

```
tkdiff -r1 abc
```

to see the difference between the current version and version 1.

This is the sort of diff I'd like to see between two versions of a file, only using Vim.  Can it be done? I'm working under Linux and I use Bitkeeper for version control.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I use the [vcscommand](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=90) plugin for interacting with a VCS.

From the description:

> VIM 7 plugin useful for manipulating files controlled by CVS, SVN, SVK and git within VIM, including committing changes and performing diffs using the vimdiff system.

In particular `:VCSVimDiff` will split the current window and show a "vimdiff" against the latest version in the repo. You can also specify one revision number to compare the current buffer to (i.e. `:VCSVimDiff -2`), or two revision numbers to diff to each other. Here is the relevant section from the docs:

> :VCSVimDiff
>
> Uses vimdiff to display differences between versions of the current
>   file.
>
> If no revision is specified, the most recent version of the file on
>   the current branch is used.  With one argument, that argument is used
>   as the revision as above.  With two arguments, the differences between
>   the two revisions is displayed using vimdiff.
>
> With either zero or one argument, the original buffer is used to perform
>   the vimdiff.  When the scratch buffer is closed, the original buffer
>   will be returned to normal mode.
>
> Once vimdiff mode is started using the above methods, additional vimdiff
>   buffers may be added by passing a single version argument to the
>   command. There may be up to 4 vimdiff buffers total.
>
> Using the 2-argument form of the command resets the vimdiff to only those 2
>   versions.  Additionally, invoking the command on a different file will
>   close the previous vimdiff buffers.

Answer (score 9):

I use vimdiff with subversion the following way:

When I want to see differences in vimdiff for a specific file or a group of files I do:

```
svn diff [files] --diff-cmd svd
```

Here the --diff-cmd instructs subversion to use the command "svd" instead of its default diff behavior.
svd is the following shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash
shift 5; /usr/bin/vimdiff -f "$@"
```

You did not mention your OS, the above will work for Linux and OS X for sure.

Comment: Instead of passing --diff-cmd as an argument, you can configure the diff-cmd in ~/.subversion/config.  One annoying thing is that svn diff launches the diff-cmd for every file separately, so I tend to do "svn diff | view -" instead.

Answer (score 2):

VCSCommand plugin is really helpful in this case and it woks seamlessly with SVN,CVS and other repositories also. `:VCSVimDiff` applies vimdiff between the file loaded in buffer and the copy in repository.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a happy user of [bazaar's vimdiff plugin](https://code.launchpad.net/~bzr/bzr-vimdiff/vimdiff). For git, there's [gitvimdiff](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1989) (and several [other solution](http://technotales.wordpress.com/2009/05/17/git-diff-with-vimdiff/) can be used). Mercurial [can do this](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/wiki/UsingVimdiffForSingleDiffs) as well.

Answer (score 0):

For ClearCase VCS there exists a [plug-in](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=15) which also does what you want.